# how to assign variable to element of string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

May be i am getting a trouble with my question, I tried to know how can my code run like this...What is my trouble, please help me
 here is my code:

```
string arr[3][4];
arr[1][0] = "34234";
printf("%s",arr[1][0]);
```

But my output is %#$ ( something like this). Please help me, thanks you very much.

Comment: `string` ?? user-defined??, `printf("%s",arr[1])`

Comment: Don't you even get a warning for this? Are you compiling without warnings enabled?

Comment: you should print using `std::cout << arr[1][0] << std::endl;`

Answer (score 5):

It's because the `printf` function knows nothing about the  C++ `std::string` class. It's there because it's part of the C standard library.

To get a C-style string that you can use in e.g. `printf` you have to use the [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method:

```
printf("%s", arr[1][0].c_str());
```

But what you *really* should do is to learn how to use the native C++ stream output:

```
std::cout << arr[1][0];
```

PS.
Instead of old C-style arrays, you should also look into the C++ [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is a C function and know nothing about types such as `std::string`. You can either use the type safe `std::cout`, from the `<iostream>` header:

```
std::cout << arr[1][0];
```

or, if you *really* need to call `printf` (and give up on type safety), call `std::string::c_str()`, which returns a `const char*` to the null-terminated string held by an `std::string`. `printf` will understand this.

```
printf("%s",arr[1][0].c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

use `std::cout` instead of `printf` with `std::string`, because C function `printf` has no view of `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>
std::cout << arr[1][0];
```

To make your code work, you need to get C char array by calling [std::string::c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) function

```
printf("%s",arr[1][0].c_str());
```